# UI not aligning

Tags: java, menu, libgdx, scene2d

I am using LibGDX and Scene2D to create a simple menu for my game.
Here is a simple example that works for me:

```
table.add(gameLogo).row();
table.add(button1).row();
table.add(button2).row();
table.add(button3).row();
```

I didn't include the irrelevant code(including the table into the stage for example).

If I don't include `.row()` to each object that I add to the table, then the menu isn't aligning to the center, which is very odd, for example:

```
table.add(gameLogo).row();
table.add(button1);
table.add(button2).row();
table.add(button3);
```

Why is the menu behaving like that? should I use more `tables` or add some `HorizontalGroups` perhaps?

If you need any additional information, or images I can provide, although it does the same for even the simplest menu implemention possible with LibGDX and Scene2d.

Comment: Images would be helpful. I don't know what you mean by "aligning to the center". `row()` tells the table that after you add that element that it should start a new row of cells.

Comment: @StrongJoshua I know what `row()` means, but thanks for explaining. By "aligning to the center" I mean that at the second example, the `gameLogo` image is aligned to the left button instead of to the center, unlike in the first example. I will try to get some images soon.

Comment: Try doing `table.add(gameLogo).align(Align.center)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a colspan problem.

Looking at your code, this is what you are currently doing :

[image]

I assume that you would like to display your menu like that :

[image]

In order to do that, as you can see, you need to set the colspan size of your gamelogo to 2, so that it will take as much size as 2 regular cells.
So, to achieve this result, your code should be :

```
table.add(gameLogo).colspan(2).center().row();
table.add(button1);
table.add(button2).row();
table.add(button3);
```

The align(Align.center) or center() methods will not work alone, since these methods are only used to align the widget inside it's **own** cell.

If you experience more problems with libgdx ui table, remember that you can enable a [debug](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table#debugging) renderer to display the cells border :

```
table.setDebug(true);
```

Comment: Thanks! I just figured out it's a table :0 Sorry about that, I guess that's what happening after a binging a programming session on my game :)

Comment: Accepted your answer!